# jquery expand toggle

Tags: jquery, toggle, expand

http://jsfiddle.net/w6eqk/1/

I want to expand content to its height (not fixed). I've done this by my self and also I've found its solution on http://jsfiddle.net/w6eqk/1/, and its working fine as expected. But it messed up when I duplicate it. i want to show toggle expand function more then 1 time. It is working fine on single only but not on multiple. here is the demo link for multi content. http://jsfiddle.net/w6eqk/129/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.view').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('view');
        var innerh= $(this).height();
        $(this).next().toggle(function(){
            $(this).prev().animate({height: innerh},200);
        },function(){
            $(this).prev().animate({height:40},200);
        });
        $(this).addClass('view');
    });
});​
```

try this instead, the toggle method fires each time the element is clicked

Comment: np, remember to accept the answer if you want people to help you in the future

Comment: thanks this works for me as expected. but seems like Chrome isn't showing expected result. The Issue is 'var innerh= $(this).height();' of content wrapper. in firefox the '.height()' is calculating exact height in px but in chrome it isn't.

I've created it in jsfiddle for demo but seems this isn't enough to understand. so I put demo url here.

jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/CxMWx/1/
site demo: http://umairdesigner.com/emagics/

on site demo please click on "Service Button" in main menu. then page will scroll down to that area and click on read more button. Check it in firefox and chrome.

Comment: it works fine in the fiddle, which leads me to believe that you have other css or js interfering with it, without taking time to troubleshoot your problem I can't really tell you what it might be, there are a lot of cross-browser differences that can give unexpected result when you combine js and css... I'm afraid you'll have to track this bug down on your own

Comment: yes it works fine in fiddle. But if any css/js file interfere with it then it will also effect in firefox. But I'm facing this issue in webkit only and even ie showing it good. here is online demo... http://umairdesigner.com/emagics/

Comment: please compare demo link in webkit and moz then you will know. open it then plz click on "Services" button in main menu. thanks in advance

Comment: I already looked at it, and no, just because some js or css interferes in chrome does not mean it will in ff or ie, because the browsers all render a little differently. I don't have time to troubleshoot your code... it works in fiddle, which means the method is sound. Something else on your page that isn't in the fiddle is causing it to react differently

Comment: Keep in mind that this method works. Not accepting answers on SO will encourage less people in the future to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just updated a bit of your code (To achieve this [effect](http://jsfiddle.net/w6eqk/129/))

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.slide').click(function() {
        $('div.view').each(function(i){
            var $dV = $(this);
            $dV.removeClass('view');  
            var innerHeight = $dV.height();
            $dV.addClass('view');
            if(!$dV.data('innerHeight')) $dV.data('innerHeight', innerHeight);
            $dV.animate({
                height: (($dV.height() == 40)? $dV.data('innerHeight')  : "40")
            }, 500);
        });
    });    
});​
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/w6eqk/131/)

Comment: thanks for your help but if i click any on it then all contents are expand. i just want only to expand clicked content.

Comment: You are welcome and no problem, I misunderstood your question. :-)

Comment: I see you got the perfect answer from `Trey`, so accept the answer.